# where can I report/get response on eclipse crashes caused by 14.02-14.04 upgrade?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, webobjects

Yes, I know. I got no rep on this site. But I have to ask this.

I upgraded my laptop, my main dev machine, from 14.02 LTS to 14.04 LTS and the plugins I use with eclipse (3.7) completely broke. I use WOLips (https://github.com/wocommunity/wolips) with eclipse. WOLips is for working with WebObjects applications.

I was getting two crashes. One would occur when editing a java file, when auto-suggest kicked in. I fixed this by adding "-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla" to the end of my eclipse.ini. I have no idea how I found that. It took a lot of random searching.

Now, I get an exception whenever I open a WOComponent:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]
```

Trying to define a XULRunnerPath just gives me even stranger errors.

I can file a bug with eclipse (which I did). I tried eclipse 4.2 and 4.4 and got other complicated integration issues. I can file a bug with mozilla (though I was not aware that they were involved). I can install a copy of xulrunner (outside of my copy of Firefox) and point to that (which I did). I can file a bug with ubuntu launchpad (which I did). None of these get you very much response.

So, I was going from one LTS to another LTS. 14.04 - 14.02 = 0.02. Not a huge deal, yes? Should I have expected problems? How can I file a bug with the people involved in just this upgrade and not the other twelve systems that this touches upon?

I had Apple laptops for a long time. I do not expect that amount of hand-holding. But I do wish someone would throw me a bone.

I can get work done if I go buy another hard disk, install 12.04 onto it and copy all of my data back. Is this really necessary? You know, I am willing to help integration testing of these releases. But the systems for finding the right place to put my oar in the water seem fairly impenetrable. Any suggestions? I do not mind working for a solution. If there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ray,

Did you try Eclipse 4.4 and use the instructions on the wiki for compiling the new WOLips? the Eclipse 4.4 is acting just fine for me (but I'm on a Mac sorry :(  )

Comment: I started to, but was hoping that I would not have to deal with all the changes from eclipse 3.7 to 4.4 just to get around this one problem with the ubuntu minor version upgrade. I am hoping we will have a downloadable WOLips for 4.4 soon so I do not have to build it myself. We will see.

Comment: Also, I had the build error last reported (from the WOEnvironment class) on the mailing list. Again, I hoped that if I waited, someone would figure out the issue.